# "Unable to determine the spatial data type in the specified dataset field..." using the map layer wizard

Tags: reporting-services, layer, spatial, spatial-query

I'm using the map layer wizard for the first time in SSRS so we can add spatial data to the map.

We get this error from the wizard:

```
Unable to determine the spatial data type in the specified dataset field...
```

The data type for the spatial data is geography.

The spatial data looks like this when executed in the Query Designer:

```
POINT (2.41866741166689 48.9082239283949)
POINT (1.92902094274567 47.9294603618455)
POINT (2.25244361602031 48.9619440062058)
POINT (1.91174331024445 47.9109595746068)
POINT (1.32766100377444 43.6203441938353)
```

If the same query is run from SSMS, it looks like this:

```
0xE6100000010C4BF382AE407448400415C84C6E590340
0xE6100000010C0287A08EF8F647409244661045DDFE3F
0xE6100000010C5A9E2FFB207B48403421972801050240
0xE6100000010C0775C6529AF44740108C3D278096FE3F
0xE6100000010C9F64447067CF45400B2CF676193EF53F
```

All help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a parameter in the where clause of your dataset?

You are are getting this error because the mapping engine is trying to sample/test run your dataset and is tripping over the parameter. Try mapping your dataset without a parameter; if it works, your issue was in the parameter, not the datatypes.

Rework your query to pull all the rows you might need, and use a filter on the dataset